# django social auth in existing project

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I want to add login from social auth in my project. i.e. I want to use django social auth.

I followed following document [document 1](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/), [document 3](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html) and "STEP-BY-STEP GUIDE TO SOCIAL LOGINS WITH DJANGO SOCIAL AUTH" document.

But after following every document, i am getting following  errors....

1.
      error when login from facebook and google_oauth2

```
Exception Type: AttributeError

Exception Value:    can't set attribute
```

and

2.
error when login from twitter.

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError

Exception Value:    Key (email)=() already exists.
```

Please help me for solving this errors or tell me how to follow these document or tell me any other document to use django social auth in my project.

I am new in django..

Answer (score 1):

Haven't got much experience working with SocialAuth, it seems here you are trying to create a new user with the same email for which the User object already exists.

I recently used "AllAuth", this seems to have a much wider utility set, is easy to integrate and support for the same is still provided. You could integrate and use the same using the following links:

- https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
- http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi Abhishek, i followed the missing django alluth tutorial, but it gives following error  


" Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains." .


in basic and advance both setting i given following url http://localhost:8000/complete/facebook